# Prevent web 'User A' viewing 'User B' records in MySQL via query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

Still new to MySQL.

I have the following MySQL table named `secrets`:

```
+----+--------+----------------+--------------------+
| id | userid |      name      | secret_ingredients |
+----+--------+----------------+--------------------+
| 72 |      1 | Nigella Lawson | Pixie dust         |
| 99 |      2 | Delia Smith    | Ground beatles     |
| 32 |      3 | Anjum Anand    | Minced fairies     |
+----+--------+----------------+--------------------+
```

I also have an HTML table that lists all the secret ingredients for each logged in user based on their SESSIONID which is their DB `userid`.

The table has a form button that posts the displayed row `id` to a php file to show all the row data on a new (details) page.

I've used the following query in the php file to pull the data:

```
$id = $_POST["secret_id"];

$userid = $_SESSION['uid'];

{

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM secrets WHERE id=" .$id );
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $secretstuff = $data['secret_ingredients'];
        $name = $data['name'];
}
```

The problem with the above is that a user can alter the `'secret_id'` value posted to the php file, and hence view another users secret ingredients.

How do I prevent this from happening.? How do I construct a query that fetches the ingredient `id` only if the `userid` matches the current `SESSION ID`?

Should I fetch all records WHERE `userid=" .$userid` and then fetch the web selected `$id` variable from the fetched array?

Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: I have a little bit of advice for you, if I may, please refrain from using mysql* extensions in php, they have been deprecated, instead switch to mysqli* or pdo*.

Comment: @Satya Thanks for the advice. I keep forgetting that.

Comment: Why are you showing the ingredients for all logged in users if you don't want to show them?

Comment: You are open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I fetch all records WHERE userid=" .$userid and then fetch the web selected $id variable from the fetched array?

Yes, you should also check the `userid` along with the `id`

Modify your query..

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM secrets WHERE id=" .$id ." AND userid = ". $userid);
if (!$result) {
    // redirect to the previous page (list page) with the message
    header('location: list.php?msg=Invalid request');
    die();
}
```

Note that if user tries to hack the form and change the `id` to check other's data you need to redirect them back because now query will return null/empty record set..

**WARNING:** mysql* functions deprecated

check [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/829533)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking at much more complicated ways to achieve this! Sooo simple. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can either store the session_id in a table somewhere that is related to that user_id (which gets into session management ) or you can obfuscate the id so its not a number. Maybe do an encrypt on it  with a hash (sha-1, md5, or something crazy like sha-256) or something.